# How to Use Vuejs on Laravel blade

Tags: laravel, api, vue.js, vue-component, laravel-blade

everyone, I want to make a dormitory management system with laravel and vuejs but I don't know how to display my data instead of "welcome.blade.php" file but instead of "blade" use vue component if someone knows this please help me how to do this. I use API route for this
thanks everyone

Answer (score 0):

You don't use it **instead** of blade you mostly use it **with** or **inside** blade.

Use Vue like normally would just treat your blade template as your plain HTML.

Comment: First, thank you but can you tell me an example, I mean a code example

Comment: Any basic Vue.js [starting guide](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/), or [boilerplate](https://jsfiddle.net/boilerplate/vue) will do, just treat blade as html that just happens get rendered by laravel.